# How can I use Apple News without changing my region on macOS Mojave?

Tags: macos, apple-news

I want to use Apple News on macOS but not to change my region to the United States. How can I do that?

Comment: can i add it to launchpad

Comment: @user7325398 type the following command into the terminal: "open /Applications/News.app" (without the quotes)

Comment: @user7325398 You can’t add it to Launchpad without using 3rd party software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access Apple News on Mac, simply enter this in Terminal. This will open the News app, no matter where it is located in on your Mac. As such, your region does not need to be set to the United States.

```
open -a "News.app"
```

If you want to access it conveniently, add the app to Dock.